# Encoding issues when export to csv from jqgrid table

Tags: csv, jqgrid

Need some help. I export data in csv format from the jqgrid table with that function:

```
    $("#table").jqGrid("exportToCsv", {
    mimetype: "text/csv;charset=utf-8",
    separator: ";",
    separatorReplace: "", // in order to interpret numbers
    quote: '"',
    escquote: '"',
    newLine: "\r\n", // navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows/) ?  '\r\n' : '\n';
    replaceNewLine: " ",
    includeCaption: true,
    includeLabels: false,
    includeGroupHeader: false,
    includeFooter: true,
    fileName: "phonebook.csv",
    returnAsString: false
})
```

It works fine. But then I open the file with Excell I see bad encoding like this:
[image]

If I open file in Notepad++ it looks good.

Can anyone help or give some advice?

Comment: Is your data in utf-8? Do you have set in your head section `<meta charset="utf-8" />` this tag. Which excel version is used? When you open with excel which charset you set before to open it?

Comment: @TonyTomov, yes I set <meta charset="utf-8" />, excell is 2016 version. When I open file with excell I didn't set the charset, but after your comment I set charset to UTF-8 and it didn't help.

Comment: Could you please prepare a simple demo with jqgrid setup and data or use jsfiddle for this purpose?